# Dynamically showing right panel with a grid

Tags: css, angular, vmware-clarity

I have a row of cards and would like that when I click on a card, there is a panel that will show up from the right and of course, push my cards.

I am pretty sure it is a matter of css, but I am very bad with that part.

Here a first draft of what it looks like:

```
<div class="row" style="padding: 2em" *ngIf="!listView">
  <div [ngClass]="gridColUnitsCss">
    <div class="row">
      <div [ngClass]="gridViewCss" *ngFor="let unit of units">
        <div class="card" (click)="backupSelectedUnit(unit)">
          <div class="card-header">
            {{ unit.s.name.value }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-2" *ngIf="showUnitDetails">
    <!-- panel info -->
  </div>
</div
```

Thanks

Comment: What does backupSelectedUnit do? I assume it somehow gives showUnitDetails a true value. Also what does 'push my cards' mean?

Comment: Angular material has a component for this. See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vkkxkepmmeno?file=app%2Fsidenav-open-close-example.ts) and here's the [link](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#opening-and-closing-a-sidenav). You can then put your grid inside that side nav.

Comment: Hi @canpan14, the backupSelectedUnit save the information of the unit and set showUnitDetails to true. For the "push my cards" is simply that by default I have 4 cards per line. If the panel shows up, I will probably have 3 per line.

Comment: Hi @Prachi, vmware-clarity has also a sidepanel, but can't find a right place in my html to put. Maybe I will push the investigation on it and try other stuff.

Comment: Clarity has a panel for sidenav, but it doesn't really have a general purpose panel for this type of use case. This is just using some CSS to animate in a container.